# How to fix cyclic dependency between java modules?

Tags: java, java-module

I'm refactoring the code so it uses modules . The problem I'm facing is, I got cyclic dependency between modules: **convertersapp, validatorsapp and modelapp**. There are 6 modules namely:

```
1. convertersapp
2. exceptionsapp
3. mainapp
4. modelapp
5. serviceapp
6. validatorapp
```

[image: Module dependencies]

My current approach - module-info. java files for every modules are:

```
1. convertersapp: module convertersapp {
  requires modelapp;
  requires gson;
  requires exceptionspp;
  requires validatorapp;
  exports converters.others to serviceapp;
  exports converters.json to modelapp;
}

2. exceptionsapp: module exceptionspp {
  exports exceptions to convertersapp, mainapp,serviceapp, modelapp;
}

3. mainapp: module mainapp {
  requires serviceapp;
  requires exceptionspp;
  requires modelapp;
}

4. modelapp: module modelapp {
  exports model to mainapp, validatorapp,convertersapp, serviceapp;
  exports model.sorting to mainapp,serviceapp;
  requires gson;
  requires exceptionspp;
  requires convertersapp;
}

5. servicapp: module serviceapp {
  exports service to mainapp;
  requires modelapp;
  requires exceptionspp;
  requires convertersapp;
}

6. validatorapp: 

  module validatorapp {
  exports validator to convertersapp;
  requires modelapp;
}
```

Comment: A cyclic dependency usually means the two modules are not separate enough to be two modules.

Comment: So, you think I should merge them together  (all 3) or even divide them into more modules?

Comment: Looking at your modules and naming, I feel like you're using the modules as packages. I believe you should convert validators, exceptions and convertors in their corresponding packages and put them in the main application module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cyclic dependency hierarchy should be avoided because it is difficult to understand and it is furthermore unclear in which order the modules should be build (A before B before C before A ...).

Common strategies:

- Merge all three modules to one
- Build a common utility module that is used by the others, but which itself does not use others.
- Move some classes to avoid the cyclicity.

Comment: Where should I put static files like json?

Comment: @Schroedinger These are resources that should be put iin `src/main/resources`.

Comment: I refactored my code into modules. Finally I don't have cyclic dependency between modules, but instead I' ve some issue with json file reading.. https://prnt.sc/n5ivbt

Comment: @Schroedinger Please ask a new question describing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A corner case, nevertheless worth to look for:

Because I was lazy, I copied the `module-info.java` file from the 'parent' module to the child, and just added the dependency to that 'parent', ending up with a module info file in the 'child' as below:

```
module com.pany.parent
{
    requires transitive com.pany.parent;
}
```

Gradle just complained about a cyclic dependency involving the module `com.pany.parent` …

Of course this was alone my fault, but after several hours working on the migration to Jigsaw, you sometimes don't see the forest because of so many trees …